# Find DHCP hostname and IP address of remote computer (behind firewall)

Tags: icloud, network, ssh, vpn

I’ve got a Mac at work, behind a firewall, with an IP address and hostname assigned via DHCP.

If I have the hostname and/or IP address, I can use ssh or a vnc client to access the machine if I activate my workplace vpn. This works fine; no additional ports need to be opened.

However, because of DHCP leases, those are liable to change occasionally. Is there any way to track them?

The computer is connected to various cloud services but none of them seem to know the correct IP address. (And it’s not clear that they would have the correct address for getting through the firewall via vpn).

- iCloud doesn’t report an IP address  anywhere obvious. Similar for Dropbox.
- I thought that the Edovia [Screens Connect](https://edovia.com/en/screens-connect/) client might help, but it doesn’t seem to have the information.
- [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) reports an IP address associated with the computer but it does not seem to be the right one (perhaps because of the firewall?).

I have also considered a ddns provider, but I’m not sure I want the required client software running on my device. macOS supports secure remote ddns via “RFC 3007” but I’m not sure if any (free?) ddns providers offer this.

My current idea, not yet implemented is:

- create a script which writes the output of `host $(hostname)` to a file. (Nb. this *is* the correct address for remote connections via the vpn.)
- Put that file at a location that is shared via iCloud Drive
- Run the script periodically via `launchd`.

This should work, but it will still require monitoring that text file by hand.

Any better ideas?

Comment: This is not really an Apple/Mac related question (it’s networking)  so it’s technically off topic.  1st, if your Mac is behind a firewall that is managed by someone else, knowing the internal IP won’t mean anything because none if the protocols will be forwarded to your machine. 2nd, when you renew a DHCP lease, it asks for the one it had last, so if your Mac had it in the last 24hrs, it will likely still have it.

Comment: 3rd, you will need to get with your network person who can set up a perm. IP  reservation and open the appropriate ports to connect to your computer. Finally, your network admin can create the necessary DNS entries so you don’t need an IP.

Comment: I was hoping for a Mac-specific answer but I understand that some aspects are more general. Fwiw, the output of `host` is indeed exactly what I need to access the machine via ssh or vnc with the vpn active. No other setup needed for ports etc.

Comment: There is no Mac specific answer as the solution is universal to both PCs and Macs. If you get a hostname from DHCP, you could try connecting to it by using it; it won’t change. Next time you are at work, open Terminal and type `hostname` to get the DHCP assigned host name.  Your network admin can assist here better than we can.

Comment: Really the correct answer is to assign the machine a static IP.

Comment: @MarcWilson that’s not always possible, obviously.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe It sounds much more like the machine shouldn't be there.